# Laravel 5.8: MorphMany relation returns Empty

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, relationship

**Comment Model:**

```php
public function commentable()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}

public function comments()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class , 'parent_id' , 'id');
}

public function setCommentAttribute($value)
{
    $this->attributes['comment'] = str_replace(PHP_EOL , "<br>" , $value);
}
```

**Post Model:**

```php
public function comments()
{
    return $this->morphMany(Comment::class, 'commentable');
}
```

And **Controller:**

```php
public function show_comments(Post $post)
{
    $comments = $post->comments()
                ->where('approved' , 1)
                ->where('parent_id', 0)
                ->latest()
                ->with(['comments' => function($query) {
                    $query->where('approved' , 1)->latest();
                }])->get();

    dd($comments);
    return view('post',compact('comments'));
}
```

Database table **Comments:**

```
Schema::create('comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->integer('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->integer('parent_id')->unsigned()->default(0);
            $table->boolean('approved')->default(0);
            $table->text('comment');
            $table->integer('commentable_id')->unsigned();
            $table->string('commentable_type');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

`$dd($comments)` returns `#items: []` or Empty. There are database records and I can access them with another methods.

I did searching alot before asking but no luck.

Comment: Can you please add the tables fields relevant to the relationships and the code posted?

Comment: @dparoli Sure, added.

Comment: Youre code seems good to me try to remove ->where('parent_id', 0) please, and see what you get. Or better debug your query just append ->toSql() in place of ->get()

Comment: Can you show us a record in your `comments` table? Possibly your `commentable_type` is incorrect. Also it might be wise to add a foreign key to your `parent_id` and make it `nullable`.

Comment: How to save model ? How to get model ? Please code share ?

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to resolve the same issue for a few hours. For anyone searching for the answer :

**Check if the `commentable_type` field in `comments` table has properly formatted route strings**

```
'commentable_type' => 'App/Models/Comment',       // Does not work

'commentable_type' => 'App\Models\Comment',      // Works
```